# Pruebas de integracion fallan por login Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test, capybara

Estoy ejecutando mis pruebas en Ruby on Rails 5.2.1.1 pero las pruebas de integración fallan.

Por ejemplo, las afirmaciones como estas:

```
test "should get index" do
  get teachers_url
  assert_response :success
end
```

arrojan esto:

**Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to http://www.example.com/users/sign_in**

Al parecer es porque no ha iniciado sesión con un usuario válido y lo redirecciona al formulario de Login.

Pensé en simular un inicio de sesión con algo como esto:

```
fill_in "user_email", with: "jdonadob@xxxxx.com"
fill_in "user_password", with: "xxxxxxx"
click_button "Iniciar sesión"
```

Pero no funciona porque el usuario no existe.  Entonces lo agrego a mis Fixtures pero no sé como escribir en el campo **encrypted_password** para que la prueba lo identifique como un usuario válido.

Agradezco si alguien me puede dar una idea de cómo se debe hacer en este caso.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿estás usando devise para autenticar? si es así, deberías seguir las indicaciones de la [documentación](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec)). En caso contrario, agrega más información de que sistema de autenticación estás usando.

Comment: Me sirvió tu recomendación.  Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la recomendación de Alter Lagos, revisé la doumentación de Devise.  Lo solucioné así:

> If you are using integration tests, to simulate a login, you can use
>   the following:

```
class SomeIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  def setup
    sign_in FactoryBot.create(:user)
  end
end
```

E instalé la gema factory_bot_rails, que a su vez instala la gema factory_bot y seguí los pasos en su documentación.

Me sirvió también leer esto:  https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md